# duplicate a page using docx-template

Tags: python-docx

from docx import Document
from docx.enum.text import WD_BREAK

def duplicate_second_page_content(doc, num_days):
# Get the content of the second page
second_page = doc.sections[1].header
content = [paragraph.text for paragraph in second_page.paragraphs]

```
# Iterate through the remaining pages and duplicate the content
for i in range(1, num_days):
    if len(doc.sections) <= i:
        # If the document has fewer sections than expected, add a new section
        doc.add_section()
    # Get the header of the current section
    current_header = doc.sections[i].header
    # Add paragraphs with the content from the second page
    for text in content:
        current_header.add_paragraph(text)

return doc
```

## Load the Word document

doc = Document('final_template.docx')

## Define the number of days

num_days = 5  # Change this to the desired number of days

## Duplicate the content and add page breaks

doc = duplicate_second_page_content(doc, num_days)

## Save the modified document

doc.save('modified_document.docx')

i wanted to create duplicate of an page in my template